# Way to filter using a backref "length" with SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, python-2.7, orm, sqlalchemy

I have a one-to-many relationship between two types of objects Message and URL. A relationship is defined in the class URL with a backref named "link" that points to Message. Is there a way to make a filter, while querying on Message, to find for example the Message that possesses less than n URLs ?

I've tried with:

```
session.query(Message).filter(len(Message.link) < n).all()
```

And with

```
from sqlalchemy import func
session.query(Message).filter(func.count(Message.link) < n).all()
```

Each of them is sending me back an error. The first one:

```
InstrumentedAttribute has no len()
```

The second:

```
DatabaseError: (DatabaseError) ORA-00934: group function is not allowed here
```

Thanks to Audrius Kažukauskas and after some fiddling I've managed to do the following query:

```
session.query(Message.message_id)\
       .join(URL)
       .group_by(Message.message_id)
       .having(func.count(URL.url_id) <= n)
```

Which works fine (send back a KeyedTuple instead of a collection of Message but I can live with it).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this to work, you need to join `Message` with `URL`, group by all fields in `Message` and do the filtering in `HAVING` clause:

```py
q = session.query(Message).\                                                     
    join(URL).\                                                                  
    group_by(Message).\                                                          
    having(func.count(URL.id) < n)
```

`filter()` (which translates to `WHERE` in SQL) is applied **before** grouping and aggregate functions, while `having()` filters rows **after** the grouping is done.

Comment: I'm getting an "DatabaseError: (DatabaseError) ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got NCLOB" error while using it (one of my column in Message has this type.

Comment: And when I put group_by(Message.message_id) I get a nice "DatabaseError: (DatabaseError) ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression" exception.....

Comment: Hm, this is strange... I have no experience with Oracle, but my query works with both PostgreSQL and SQLite (even after modifying `group_by()` like you did). Though I must note that the models I've created to test the query were very simple.

Comment: The issue was coming of a damn clob, if I put the whole object in the query like that query(Message), cx_Oracle was freaking out about the comparison but if I put a specific column (query(Message.message_id)) that has a "nice" type, e.g. an integer, the comparator is happy about it and sends back results.